# Creating a large 1D matrix returning exit 11

Tags: c++, matrix

I have wrote some code that uses a 1D array to represent a matrix. I am currently testing large input sizes.

When I set `rows` and `cols` to `50000` the program exits with code 11.

I tried printing a lot out.

```
double* create_matrix_1d(int n_rows, int n_cols) {
    long long len = (long long ) n_rows * (long long) n_cols;

    auto* A = new double[len];

    int row, col ;

    for(row = 0; row < n_rows; row++) {
        for( col = 0; col < n_cols; col++) {
            int i = col + row * n_cols;

            A[i] = 1; //static_cast <int> (rand()) % 10 ;
        }
    }

    return A;
}
```

Comment: 19GB is quite a lot of memory to request.

Comment: Is that Segmentation fault?

Comment: No. `std::bad_alloc` is thrown when `new` can't allocate enough memory.

Comment: why do you need 50000*50000 matrices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's compute the required memory. A double generally uses 8 bytes, hence your matrix requires:

```
50000*50000*8 = 20000000000 bytes
```

of memory

```
20000000000 bytes = 20000000000 / 1024 = 19531250 kb

19531250 / 1024 = 19073 Mb

19073  / 1024 = 18.6265 Gb
```

So unless you have a computer with more that 19 Gb of RAM it is normal that you get some out of memory error

Comment: I haven't tested yet. Don't know about computer architecture. But what if I used 2D array?

Comment: The problem will be the same, you will still have to store 19Gb of doubles. Generally big matrices are sparse. Under this condition more efficient storage schemes exist, like [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix)

Answer (score 0):

the answer should be easy. But I cannot be sure, because you gave not enough information about your compiler, the language and your hardware. And most important, I do net see a question.

But we guess that you want to know, why you routine fails.

Next. I was not sure, what language you use. It looks like Plain old C, but for whatever reason, you used the keyword auto and a static_cast in a comment. So, it 'should' be C++.

First the answer, then some additional comments:

Your are trying to allocate 19GB on the heap. Depending on the memory model that you are using and the availibilty of pyhsical RAM, this will most probably fail.

Additionally your are writing

> int i = col + row * n_cols;

This will create an overflow.

Second:  Some improvement proposals.

If you are unsing modern C++, then you should use modern C++. Sounds strange, but your Code is C-Style.

The, if you really want to handle big data, you could consider a database. But I doubt that you really need 19GB of filled data. There are other techniques availible to store only needed data. You need to change your algoritm.

I commented your code to give at least some proposals for improvement:

```
// Rows and Cols could be made const. They are not modified in your code
// If you anyway later cast to long long, then you could also make the parameters long long
// You should use unique_ptr to take ownership of the allocated memory
// But this cannot be copied and needs to be "moved" out of the function
// You should use a C++ container to hold your matrix, like a std::vector
double* create_matrix_1d(int n_rows, int n_cols) {
    // You should not use C-Style Cast but static_cast
    long long len = (long long ) n_rows * (long long) n_cols;
    // You should use a unique_ptr to handle the resource
    auto* A = new double[len];

    int row, col ;

    for(row = 0; row < n_rows; row++) {
        for( col = 0; col < n_cols; col++) {
            // The "int i" can most likely hold only (2^32-1)
            // SO you will get an overfolow here
            int i = col + row * n_cols;
            // You wanted to assign an int to a double
            A[i] = 1; //static_cast <int> (rand()) % 10 ;
        }
    }

    return A;
}
```

Hope, this helps

Answer (score 0):

The question has been already answered by Vincent.

I just leaving a few comments about the written code:

- It is always safer to use [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization), using stdlib data structures like `vector` should help
- Also the nested loops could have written as--

```
for(int i=0; i<nrows*ncols; ++i)
  A[i] = 1.0;
```

Helps the compiler to act a bit smarter by mapping to [vectorized instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_vectorization).

Happy coding!